# Inconsistent display names of user account in ASP.NET MVC4 SimpleMembership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, simplemembership

I am building a ASP.NET MVC4 Internet website using Visual Studio 2012.

VS2012 generated a template website by default, with SimpleMembership implemented.

The SimpleMembership feature is quite convinient, expect that there is one thing very confusing to me:

For example, I create a user account, with the user name say "Miles", and then login using the name "Miles", everthing is fine. Then I logout and login using the name "miles"(all lower case), the login is also sucessful, however, the user name reads "miles". To be more specific, the value of User.Identity.Name is "miles", instead of "Miles" in the database.

Likewise, I can use "miLes", "mILes", "MILES", etc. to login, and the user name will be the same. The common sense is that if the authentication is case-insensitve, the user name should be exactly the same as the one in database, in my case "Miles", not as what I type in the login textbox.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reason

In your AccountController you probablay see something like this by default:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```

`WebSecurity.Login()` is called (passing in the exact string on the model that you typed in your form).

If you look at the source code of [WebSecurity.cs](https://github.com/aspnetwebstack/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebMatrix.WebData/WebSecurity.cs) you'll see that `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` is called (again, still passing the exact typed string).  Before this methods actually sets the cookie in the response, it executes `GetAuthCookie()`, still passing in the exact string you typed when logging in.

This method actually builds out the authentication `HttpCookie` object once again using the data you typed in.

### Solution

If you need the name to match exactly what's in your database, then you need to query for the record from the database and pass that value into `WebSecurity.Login()`.

Comment: I see what's going on in the source code. Thanks!

Seemingly SimpleMembership can hardly meet the demands of an average Internet website. One might also **bool success = Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password);** looks more like **LoginInfo logininfo = Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password);**, where logininfo contains actual user name, unread messages and so on.

Rewriting/extending it kinda breaks the DRY principle. I am considering abandoning it and use a 3rd party Nuget package. Any recommendation?

Comment: I would look into ASP.NET Identity.  I never used SimpleMembership in any of my applications (I'm still on good ol' Forms Authentication with the Membership Provider).  I am planning on using ASP.NET Identity though either later this year or next year.